# Proving an integral identity

Tags: hilbert-spaces, improper-integrals

I'm dealing with the Hermitian operator, and I've been asked to prove that all $f(x) = x^n e^{\alpha x}$ belong to $L^2(-\infty,\infty;e^{-x^2/2})$ by showing that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^m e^{2\alpha x}e^{-x^2/2}dx = e^{2\alpha^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x+2\alpha)^me^{-x^2/2}dx$$

Of course, after proving the identity, it is clear that all $f(x)$ of this particular form will belong, because you've simplified this integral to an $m^{th}$ degree polynomial, and all polynomials will belong to $L^2(-\infty,\infty;e^{-x^2/2})$.

I'm not sure if it is of any use to recognize that this is just $<x^m,e^{\alpha x}>$ (Hermite inner product), or if I just need to start integrating by parts a whole bunch.. Any help please :)

Comment: What do you want exactly? If you say "it is clear that all $f(x)$...", then you  are done. If you recognize an inner product, then you have to justify that both $x^m$ and $e^{ax}$ belong to $L^2(\mathbf R,e^{-x^2/2})$, which is not much simpler than the initial problem.

Comment: The question is to prove the identity, not the implication afterward,since I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove the identity, we have to complete the squares; more precisely: 
$$-\frac{x^2}2+2\alpha x=-\frac 12\left(x^2 -2\cdot 2\alpha x\right)= -\frac 12\left((x-2\alpha)^2-4\alpha^2\right).$$
Therefore, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^m e^{2\alpha x}e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx
=e^{2\alpha^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^m\exp\left(-\frac{\left(x-2\alpha\right)^2} 2\right)\mathrm dx.$$
To conclude, use the substitution $t:=x-2\alpha$ (the bounds are unchanged and $\mathrm dx=\mathrm dt$).